# Destination ViewController from UIStoryboardSegueTemplate

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to programatically get all the segues attached to UIViewController using UIStoryboardSegueTemplate and my aim is to get the destination view controller to the segue associated.

So far I have done:

```
func initViewControllers(){

    guard let array = self.value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? [AnyObject] else {
        //No segues
        return
    }

    for item in array{
        print("\(logClassName): initViewControllers -> Self = \(String(describing: item.self))")
        print("\(logClassName): initViewControllers -> Segue Identifier = \(String(describing: item.value(forKey: "identifier")))")
        print("\(logClassName): initViewControllers -> Class = \(String(describing: item.value(forKey: "segueClassName")))")
        print("\(logClassName): initViewControllers -> Destination = \(String(describing: item.value(forKey: "destinationViewControllerIdentifier")))")


        let segueClassName:String = (item.value(forKey: "segueClassName") as? String) ?? ""
        if segueClassName.contains("CustomTabSegue"){
            print("\(logClassName): appending tabItem VC")
            let segueContainer:String = (item.value(forKey: "identifier") as? String) ?? ""
            performSegue(withIdentifier: segueContainer, sender: self)
        }

   }
}
```

and getting the Destination using `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

The way I select the segues I want to catch is by a custom class called `CustomTabSegue`

The question is: Is there a way to get the destination View controller without performing the segue?

According to this [link](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStoryboardSegueTemplate.h) it seems unlikely but maybe there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the answer of Agent Smith, I have been able to do:

```
func initViewControllers(){

    guard let array = self.value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? [AnyObject] else {
        return
    }

    for item in array{

        if let segueClassName = (item.value(forKey: "segueClassName") as? String){

            if segueClassName.contains("CustomTabSegue"){
                print("\(logClassName): CustomTabSegue")

                if let destinationViewController = (item.value(forKey: "destinationViewControllerIdentifier") as? String)?.components(separatedBy: "-").first{
                    print("\(logClassName): DestinationVC = \(destinationViewController)")

                    if let addedVC = destinationViewController.getViewController(){
                        print("\(logClassName): Adding View Controller \(addedVC.logClassName)")
                        viewControllers.append(addedVC)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
}
```

And I have created the following extension

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension String{

func getViewController() -> UIViewController? {

    if var appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
        print("CFBundleName - \(appName)")
        appName = appName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_", options: .literal)

        if let viewControllerType = NSClassFromString("\(appName).\(self)") as? UIViewController.Type {
            print("String: as UIViewController")
            return viewControllerType.init()
        }

    }

    return nil
}
```

It works as expected but the only problem a now is that if the ViewController in embedded in a UINavigationController it won't detect it

Answer (score 1):

If you created those segues yourself, What I did was, I gave the identifier to the segue as :-

```
ViewControllerName1 + "To" + ViewControllerName2
```

After getting the list of segues from **storyboardSegueTemplates** I separated them with `To` and got the name of both source and destination ViewControllers. Then, Converting them to **Class** type by

```
NSClassFromString(ClassName: String)
```

This way you can get the type of classes which are associated with segues but it's impossible to get the instances of **destinationViewControllers** because they are not initialized until you do :

```
 performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?)
```

Hope it helps!!